# Python Submit form

Tags: python, forms, submit

I would like to fill in and submit a form on a web page using python.

This form:

```
<form method="POST" id="login" action="site/enter.php" >
  <input type="text" placeholder="Login" name="login" class="login" tabindex="1">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" class="password" tabindex="2">
  <input type="submit" class="btn_auth" value="" title="Enter" tabindex="3">
</form>
```

But can't do it. I place login and pass, but can't emulate submit button.

Comment: What? What kind of web-framework are you using, if any? What are you having troubles with? We need waaaay more info.

Comment: Please post the non-working code, otherwise this question is way too vague.

Comment: This looks like a job for Selenium Webdriver!

Comment: cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        values = dict(login=username, psw=userpass, frm='submit')
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(root_url, data)
        home_page = opener.open(req)
        page_text=home_page.read()
        print page_text

Comment: you have to use something like cURL to post your form.

Comment: [you can edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11742435/edit), put the code from your comment in there (don't forget to format it)

Comment: what result do you get, what do you expect instead? Browser sends nothing for "submit". Compare it with what your code sends.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to use selenium's Webdriver to drive webpages than to use something like mechanize. Especially if the page is dynamically created.

You'll need to install selenium. `pip install selenium` should work. You'll also need a version of Firefox installed.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.get('http://some_url.com')
browser.find_element_by_id('login').send_keys('your_login') 
browser.find_element_by_name('pws').send_keys('your_password')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn_auth').click() 

print browser.page_source
browser.close()
```

Comment: unless the page uses JavaScript. It is an overkill

Comment: Well, since so much of the web is now rendered with JS I find it's best to go there first. What part didn't work Ur Riv?

Comment: It just open Chrome and don't do anything

Comment: So there is no stacktrace? I noticed an extra space in my code which I just removed? You aren't just blindly copying this are you?

Comment: @aychedee - I'm getting a message `'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'implicitly'`. What is that line supposed to do? Does leaving it off change how this works?

Comment: Looks like it was changed at some point, I've updated the code. Thanks for noticing! It sets a timeout in seconds for the browser to wait for things to be visible. It helps a lot with elements that are rendered with JavaScript.

Comment: @aychedee - Ah, I see. I left that off and it worked fine for me, but none of the pages I'm using this for rely on JavaScript for rendering. I've already +1'd your answer, but something that would improve it would be some documentation on getting `selenium` set up. Took me around 10 minutes to figure it out. I had to first use `pip` to install selenium, then visit http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html for the latest driver, then I downloaded that and added it to my Windows Path. Then I restarted cmd. Adding it to my Python Path didn't work as I assumed it would.

Comment: Alternatively you can just use `browser = webdriver.Firefox()`, maybe I'll change that. It just requires a version of Firefox to be installed.