# Python Submit a form and get response

Tags: python

My general question : How could i submit a form and then get response from website with a python program ?

My specific : I want to send some thing like Ajax XHR send to a web file and get response from it , problematically .

- I don't want to use any browser and do it in the code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742435/python-submit-form) link.
- I have read [this](http://python.dzone.com/articles/how-submit-web-form-python) articles and they just make me confused and can't find good documented about it.

Comment: you wanna get the response "problematically"??? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Tell us more. Are you trying to access a GET or POST website, does it have an API etc

Comment: I want to send or POST a XHR request to a webpage and get response which that could be save as a file with a response.I want to analyse that response in my program.

Comment: Why not just use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)?

Comment: Okey let my try once more.thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is very easy too!

Here is the example from their homepage pertaining to POSTing forms

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print r.text
{
 ...
"form": {
"key2": "value2",
"key1": "value1"
   },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib
import urllib2 

data = {
    'field1': 'value1',
    'field2': 'value2',
}

req = urllib2.Request(url="http://some_url/...",
                      data=urllib.urlencode(data), 
                      headers={"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}) 
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```